# Jpanels on top of other panels, disappear when objects interact. - java swing interface

Tags: java, validation, swing, jpanel, repaint

OK, I hope to explain this the best I can.

What's up is that I have an outer `JPanel` with a board game image, and an inner `JPanel`
with the location menus, next turn, roll dice buttons etc.

I make my board markers move from one side of the board to the other, but the inside parts of the board disapear as this happens.

I tried doing `revalidate();` `repaint();` and everything for the outer, and inner panels, the board image, also buttons etc, but I'm still faced with this problem.

Hope someone can help.  Thanks.

Comment: Yea show us some code. Especially how you are painting these panels.

Comment: -1 'some code' +1 [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  The OP will always guess the wrong part of the code to copy.  (Andrew's 'copy/paste debugging' corollary to Murphy's law.)  And to the OP - now I can read your post, I'm wondering - did you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like OP may have abandoned this, but I'll take a complete shot in the dark: try turning off the `optimizedDrawingEnabled` flag on one (or both?) of the containers. Swing expects that siblings never overlap - if they do, you need to turn off that flag.